# If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then $F'$ is continuous at $c$ where $ F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\ dt$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$, let $c\in(a, b)$, and let
$\displaystyle F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\ dt$, $a\le x\le b$. For the following statement, give either a proof or a counterexample:

> If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then $F'$ is continuous at $c$.

**My attempt:**

My hunch is that the statement is false. Since $f$ is differentiable at $c$, $f$ is continuous at $c$ and so by the first Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F'(c)=f(c)$. But $F'$ need not be equal to $f$ at other points.

Is this correct? If so, how do I find a counterexample? If not, how do I prove the statement?

Comment: Riemann or Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: @Momo Riemann integrable

Comment: I think that one would like to check the continuity of $F(x)$, rather than that of $F'(x)$ as, by the theorem, you get $F'(x)=f(x)$ in the interval including $c$, and as $f$ is differentiable, then it is continuous at that point.

Comment: The existence of $f'(c)$ does not imply $F'$ exists in a neighborhood of $c.$ For example, $f$ could have a bunch of jump discontinuities near $c,$ and we know that at a jump discontinuity, $F'$ won't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a counterexample where $F'$ fails to exist at infinitely many points $x_n \to c$ and is technically not continuous at $c$, but where $f'(c)$ exists.

For example, take $c= 0$ and $f:[0,1/2] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and for $x \in (0,1/2]$ and $k = 1,2, \ldots$

$$f(x) = x^2 \begin{cases}\,\,\,\,\,1, \,\,\,\, x\in \left(\frac{1}{2k+1},\frac{1}{2k}\right] \\ -1, \,\,\,\, x\in \left(\frac{1}{2k+2},\frac{1}{2k+1}\right] \end{cases}$$

Comment: So $F'$ fails to exist at each $1/m, m>2.$ Is that the point here?

Comment: Why the alteration? All you seem to be saying is that $F'$ doesn't exist everywhere in some neighborhood of $0$. That' what you had before, Is that right?

Comment: That's the extent of it.

Comment: I suppose it becomes a technicality as to the definition of continuity or how the derivative is defined at those points.

Comment: Does your function $f$ look like two parabolas one concave the other convex meeting at the origin, changing from convex to concave infinitely many times for every subinterval, and with jump discontinuities at every $1/m$  So the graph of $F$ looks like a jagged $xsin(1/x)$ graph that is not differentiable at every $1/m$?

Comment: @helios321:  Yes and $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = 0$ exists.  But in one sense the limit of $F'$ does not exist.  However with the domain restricted it does.  This question came up a second time -- answered in different ways -- one similar to this.  I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @helios321: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2046773/148510) for the same question asked 3 days later.   As you can see one answer is similar to mine stating that if $F'$ fails to exist in a "full neighborhood" of $c$ then we technically can't say it is continuous at $c$.