# Looking for weird counterexample for Riemann integrability question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, riemann-integration

I am looking for a counterexample to the following:

> Let $f$ be [Riemann] integrable $[a,b]$, let $c \in (a,b)$, and let $$F(x) = \int_a^xf$$ for $a\leq x\leq b$.
>
> Find $f,c$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $c$, but $F'$ is not continuous at $c$.

I've been working on this with multiple people for quite some time, and though the solution says a counterexample exists, we have not been able to find one.

Comment: I very much suspect it was a typo in the problem statement, and they meant to write "Find $f,c$ such that $F$ is differentiable at $c$, but $F'$ is not continuous at $c$".

Comment: @DanielFischer It is not a typo. I have spoken with the professor.

Comment: Then they are mistaken. Or they have a non-standard definition of continuity.

Comment: What is the issue with this counter-example mentioned in this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2047181/72031 of your previous question?  It gives you exactly the function you need.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I disagree. With the $f$ of that answer, $F'$ is continuous on its entire domain.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That is the best possible we can hope for. As your answer says,  we can't have $F'$ discontinuous at continuity of $f$. Only thing we may have is that $F'$ does not exist at points arbitrarily near $c$ and that linked answer gives that kind of example. Like you I also suspect a typo in the question. If the typo is corrected then $f(x) = \cos(1/x), c = a = 0$ is the example we need.

Answer (score 3):

As I commented, I expect that the problem statement should have been

> Find $f,c$ such that $F$ is differentiable at $c$, bit $F'$ is not continuous at $c$.

Finding examples for that, while not trivial, is not exceedingly difficult.

If we require that the integrand $f$ is differentiable at $c$, it becomes impossible to find an example. It is already impossible if we merely require $f$ to be continuous at $c$. We can write

$$F(x) = F(c) + f(c)(x-c) + \int_c^x \bigl(f(t) - f(c)\bigr)\,dt.$$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. By the continuity of $f$ at $c$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert f(t) - f(c)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $t \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$. Then, for $x,y \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$ with $x < y$ we have

$$F(y) - F(x) = f(c)(y-x) + \int_x^y \bigl(f(t) - f(c)\bigr)\,dt,$$

and so

$$\Biggl\lvert \frac{F(y) - F(x)}{y-x} - f(c)\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{y-x}\int_x^y \lvert f(t) - f(c)\rvert\,dt < \varepsilon.$$

Thus at all points of $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ where $F$ is differentiable, we have

$$\lvert F'(x) - f(c)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon.$$

So $F'$ is continuous at $c$.

Note: There can be points arbitrarily close to $c$ where $F$ is not differentiable, but that doesn't affect the continuity of $F'$ at $c$, for that one considers only the domain of $F'$.

If it was meant that there is no neighbourhood $(c-\eta, c+\eta)$ of $c$ such that $F$ is differentiable at all points of that neighbourhood, just take an $f$ that has a sequence of jump discontinuities converging to $c$. Such functions are easy to find even when one requires differentiability at $c$.